# In WiX, what's the correct way to enable .NET 3.5?

Tags: wix, .net-3.5, bootstrapper

I'm creating an installer for a Windows desktop app, which has a dependency on another product that requires .NET 3.5

When installing this on Windows 10, .NET 3.5 is included and has to be enabled in Add/Remove Windows Features. I don't think it is valid to install a downloadable version of .NET 3.5 on Windows 10 (correct me if I'm wrong!).

So, is there a way to get WiX to enable the .NET 3.5 "feature" rather than downloading and installing it?

Comment: In all honesty, the *correct* way is **to not install it**. As we have been told by MS .NET 4.x should be backward compatible. You should avoid it like the plague. Also, there are now developer versions (> 3.14) of *wixtoolset* that does a registry hack to avoid users to have to install that old legacy *"malware"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to install .NET 3.5 on Windows 10 and the latest Windows Server: to update a group policy value that will allow to download .NET 3.5 ([blog post](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6615/error-installing-microsoft-net-framework-3-5-sql-server/)).

> ...open the command prompt and type "gpedit". The "Local Computer Policy Editor" opens where we can locate the necessary setting under the "Computer Configuration" > "Administrative Templates" > "System". On the left side, under "Settings", we can find a setting named "Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair"
> [image: policy list]
> This is what we are going to modify. Let's open it and check "Enabled" and then check the second option – "Download repair content and optional features directly from Windows Update instead of Windows Server Update Services (WSUS)" and click "OK":
> [image: policy settings]
> Now, if we retry adding the .NET Framework 3.5, we can see that it succeeds...

I personally then revert this policy setting to its original value, if it was different.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this is the *correct* way but you can try a custom action with the following command

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3
```

You can get a list of all available features by `dism /online /get-features` if you want to try other windows features.

Comment: You might be able to invoke this from a `setup.exe` bundle? Be aware that this might be frowned upon to do without asking the user - but I guess that will ask the user?

Comment: I've also had this fail a lot and then people call in saying they can't install even if you put an informative message about it being a Microsoft/OS issue. Because it happened in *your* installer, it's your problem. Typically for dism stuff I like to just have the user do it themselves and fail the install with a launch condition until they do it.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I would use another setup msi to wrap that custom action, or use `<ExePackage>`directly. sth like`<ExePackage SourceFile="C:\Windows\System32\dism.exe" InstallCommand="/online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFx3" ..>`  -- not tested though

Answer (score 0):

> ***WiX Samples***: Some potentially helpful links in general:
>
> - [WiX Quick Start Suggestions (with sample links)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864).
> - https://helgeklein.com/blog/2014/09/real-world-example-wix-msi-application-installer/

---

***Alternative Tools***: Maybe keep in mind that commercial tools have features that are easier to use to get your product out there quickly. WiX is great though.

- [MSI Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840) (comparing different MSI tools)
- [On WiX, setup GUI and Commercial tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52446750/removing-default-dialogs-from-msi)

---

***Prerequisites***: I would suggest you add a LaunchCondition to the package to abort installation if the .NET framework is not there. You can bundle the .NET framework with your application, but I really do not recommend that: [Outdated prerequisites in packages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57005567/129130).

***LaunchCondition***: The concept of LaunchConditions checks for a certain condition to be true before installation is allowed to continue:

- **[Check if prerequisites are installed before installing a windows installer package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55121149/check-if-prerequisites-are-installed-before-installing-a-windows-installer-packa/55183152#55183152)** (please check this link at the very least - if you don't check other links)
- [An earlier answer on LaunchConditions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49868953/129130).

***Quick, inline sample***:

```
<Condition Message="The .NET Framework 2.0 must be installed">
    Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20
</Condition>
```

---

***WiX and .NET Framework***: Some built-in measures to detect the .NET framwork.

- [**How To: Check for .NET Framework Versions**](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html) (official WiX documentation)
- [How to check for .net framework 4.7.1 with Wix 3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778581/how-to-check-for-net-framework-4-7-1-with-wix-3-11)
- [How can I detect whether .NET Framework 4.6.1 or higher is installed in WiX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401019/how-can-i-detect-whether-net-framework-4-6-1-or-higher-is-installed-in-wix/37401225)

---

***Link***:

- [Wix IIS Version check launch condition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52518448/wix-iis-version-check-launch-condition-not-working/52526661#52526661)
- [LaunchConditions and missing runtimes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49015801/129130)