# Enable .NET Framework 3.5 in windows 10 using WiX installer

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wix3.6, wix3.11

I am creating an MSI which need .Net framework 3.5 to be enabled in windows 10. For that I Created a bundle but its not enabling .net framework.

same I can do it manually by going control panel and enable through windows feature

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
         xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
        <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="My Technologies" UpgradeCode="820e4036-1460-4ad3-aca6-ffee620e8778">
            <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />

        <Chain>
          <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
          <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
          <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40ClientWeb"/>
          <MsiPackage Id="MyApplication" SourceFile="C:\My App\Output\MyAPp.msi"/>
        </Chain>
        </Bundle>
      <Fragment>
          <!-- Check for .NET 4.0 -->
          <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                               Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033"
                               Value="Version"
                               Variable="Netfx4FullVersion" />
          <util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                               Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full\1033"
                               Value="Version"
                               Variable="Netfx4x64FullVersion"
                               Win64="yes" />
        <PackageGroup Id="NetFx40ClientWeb">
          <ExePackage Id="NetFx40ClientWeb"
                      DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0"
                      DownloadUrl="https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/confirmation.aspx?id=1639"
                      Compressed="no"
                      Cache="yes"
                      PerMachine="yes"
                      Permanent="yes"
                      Protocol="netfx4"
                      Vital="yes"
                      SourceFile=".\NetFx20SP2_x64.exe"
                      InstallCommand="/passive /norestart"
                      DetectCondition="Netfx4FullVersion AND (NOT VersionNT64 OR Netfx4x64FullVersion)" />
        </PackageGroup>
      </Fragment>
    </Wix>
```

IS there any way to enable it, because I think windows 10 already have .net package preinstall and we need to just enable it.

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57300423/in-wix-whats-the-correct-way-to-enable-net-3-5)?

Comment: Yes I tried this but its not working in windows 10, 64 bit OS